# Обработка формы на ajax laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Всем доброго времени суток. Изучаю `laravel`. Разобрался с маршрутизацией и сборкой дизайна, добрался до обработки форм. Тестирую на исходниках прошлого учебного проекта, собранного на `php+ajax` `jquery+mysql`. Хочу отработать форму комментирования статьи. Код исходников прилагается ниже

**Контроллер indexController, метод comment**

```
<?php
public function comment(request $input){
  //$input = $request->all();
  $this->validate($input, [
  'name' => 'required|max:100',
  'message' => 'required|unique:comments,message',
   'article_id' => 'required|articles,id'
  ]);
  $data = array('name' => $input['name'],
      'message' => $input['message'],
      'article_id' => $input['article_id']);
  $result = DB::table('comments')->insert($data);
  if ($result == true) $response = 0;
  else $response = 'error';
  return json($response);
  }
?>
```

**Фрагмент вида `article-content.blade.php`, форма добавления комментария и аякс обработчик**

```
    <form method="post" action="" id="comment_form">
     <ul>
     <li>
     <label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
     <input type="text" id="name" required class="required" placeholder="Ваше имя">
     </li>
     <li>
     <label for="message">Комментарий:</label>
     <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="100" rows="6" required  class="required" ></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" id="article_id" value="{{$article->id}}">
      </li>
      <li>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button fright">Оставить комментарий</button>
      <span id="resp"></span>
      {{csrf_field()}}
      </li>
      </ul>
      </form>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var time = new Date();
      var date = time.getFullYear()+"-" +(time.getMonth()+1)+ "-" +time.getDate()+ " " +time.getHours()+ ":"+time.getMinutes()+ ":"+time.getSeconds();
      $("#comment_form").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/comment',
      data: $("#comment_form").serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
      var messageResp = new Array('Ваше сообщение отправлено');
      var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
      if(response == 0){
      $("#name").val("");
      $("#message").val("");
      $("#comments").append('<ol class="comments"><li class="comment"><h6>'+name+' <span class="meta">'+date+'</span></h6><p>'+message+'</p></li></ol>');
      }
$("#resp").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
return false;
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

**Запись в маршрутизаторе `route/web.php`**

```
Route::post('/comment', 'IndexController@comment');
```

Собственно вопрос в том, что на сервер приходит урезанный набор полей: инпуты `name` и `article_id` не отправляются, в связи с чем валидация не проходит и метод `comment` возвращает ошибку. Хотелось бы узнать, почему так происходит. Заранее спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте атрибуты `name`. То есть, должно быть так:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required class="required" placeholder="Ваше имя">
```

и

```
<input type="hidden" id="article_id" name="article_id" value="{{$article->id}}">
```

---

Атрибут id [задает стилевой идентификатор — уникальное имя элемента, которое используется для изменения его стиля и обращения к нему через скрипты. Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз.](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id)

А атрибут name [определяет уникальное имя элемента формы. Как правило, это имя используется при отправке данных на сервер или для доступа к введенным данным поля через скрипты.](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/name)

Answer (score 0):

Решил почти также. Токен передал в мета-теге в шапке (вот так `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />`), а в аякс-обработчике сделал захват по атрибуту name мета-тега. Поскольку для сборки страниц использую единую шапку, то токен теперь на всех контентных страницах, так или иначе взаимодействующих с аякс. Сериализацию данных формы сменил на жесткую передачу конкретных параметров (name, message, article_id и token) И все заработало. Аналогично разобрался со всеми формами на аякс по проекту.
Вот итог, если кому нужно:

**Обновленный фрагмент вида article-content.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="comment_form">
<ul>
<li>
<label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" required class="required" placeholder="Ваше имя">
</li>
<li>
<label for="message">Комментарий:</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="100" rows="6" required  class="required" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="article_id" value="{{$article->id}}">
</li>
<li>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button fright">Оставить комментарий</button>
<span id="resp"></span>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
<script>
$("#comment_form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var name = $("#name").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
var article_id = $("#article_id").val();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/comment',
data: {"name": name, "message": message, "article_id": article_id, "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
success: function(response){
var messageResp = new Array('Ваше сообщение отправлено');
var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
if(response == 0){
$("#name").val("");
$("#message").val("");
$("#comments").append('<ol class="comments"><li class="comment"><h6>'+name+' <span class="meta">'+date+'</span></h6><p>'+message+'</p></li></ol>');
}
$("#resp").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
return false;
}
});
});
</script>
```

**P.S.:** Большое спасибо за ответ. Разобрался в тот же день, когда выложил вопрос, просто не было времени написать сюда.